# OrientDB edge class inheritance ignored

Tags: java, orientdb

im working right now on a problem with edges.
i created this edge type in a graph without transactions:

```
this.graph.createEdgeType("edge", null);
```

So there is now an edge type `edge` with the parent `E`.
When i now create an edge of the created edge type (in a graph with transactions):

```
Edge edge = this.graph.addEdge("class:edge", outVertex, inVertex, "example");
```

and add a property to it:

```
edge.setProperty("property", "example");
```

He is creating a new class `example` as subclass of `E`:

```
WARNING: Committing the active transaction to create the new type 'example' 
as subclass of 'E'. The transaction will be reopen right after that. 
To avoid this behavior create the classes outside the transaction.
```

Why is he not taking my `edge` type which i created as superclass
of the `example` edge?
Why is he creating a new type as subclass of `E`?

I do the same thing with Vertices but the difference is it works:

```
this.graph.createVertexType("person", null);

Vertex vertex = this.graph.addVertex("class:person", null, "person");
vertex.setProperty("name", "peter");
```

No problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the edge's label as class.:

```
Edge edge = this.graph.addEdge("class:example", outVertex, inVertex, "example");
```

Comment: This is a low quality answer. Please provide additional explanation, or it may be removed.

Comment: Its okay, i got what he means (polymorphism).